# J2ME Polish Textfields and Symbian^3 Touch Devices

Tags: mobile, java-me, symbian, textfield, j2mepolish

today's question is about the use of textfields in J2ME Polish for Symbian^3 devices.

In my code I have something like this:

`TextField digitValueText = new TextField ("Number", "", 1, TextField.NUMERIC);`

This works perfectly fine on other symbian devices (s40, s60, etc), however, when I go and test it on a Nokia N8 (Symbian^3) I can't input numbers, nor does the device allow me to select the textfield to popup the keyboard.

Has anyone else gone through this problem?

the textField has to be numbers-only since we don't want the users to input text (it's for authentication).

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT: So it seems that this behavior is from polish.TextField.useDirectInput, TextField.NUMERIC inherits the behavior by default...
still any ideas on this?

Comment: does NUMERIC `TextBox` suffer from the same bug?

Comment: will be testing this in a couple of mins

Comment: Same thing happens with TextBox

Comment: interesting. Their user guide claims their [virtual keyboard](http://www.nokia.ie/ie-en/support/product/n8-00/userguide/?action=onlineuserguidepagechange&pFile=GUID-B7DB89EE-4255-4351-B455-AF7554AF8C8F_FILE001.html) should pop-up and that it can do numeric input - does it fail even with TextBox?

Comment: @gnat this problem only occurs when using J2ME Polish. I've tried with  native J2ME and it works fine.

Comment: I see. Looks like a bug in _Polish_, then. Does Polish allow you to pop-up "raw" MIDP TextBox from its screen? if yes, that could probably make a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the project configuration to Generic/AnyPhone.